# Python 'resource' module - Negative values and unrecognised RLIMIT_VMEM

Tags: python, resources

I am using the Python [resource module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) in order to limit my memory usage, in the following way:

```py
import resource
rsrc = resource.RLIMIT_AS
soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(rsrc)
resource.setrlimit(rsrc, (soft, 5*1024*1024))  # hard limit = 5GB
```

However, I encountered the following problems:

1. The current `hard` limit is `-1`. What is the meaning of this value? The problem is that, because it is negative, I cannot set the hard limit to anything higher, and I get an error message (`ValueError: current limit exceeds maximum limit`).
2. Contrary to the documentation, the `resource` module has no `RLIMIT_VMEM`. When trying to access `resource.RLIMIT_VMEM`, I get an error (`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLIMIT_VMEM'`). Could this be caused by some compatibility issues with my OS?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between RLIMIT_MEM and RLIMIT_AS?

Comment: Aren't the input units bytes? Doesn't your limit of `5*1024*1024` equal to 5MB rather than 5GB?

Comment: @Cyrille I suspected also...

Answer (score 2):

If you read the man page for the `getrlimit()` Linux C call and the `prlimit` command line tool, they vaguely allude to the fact that -1 is the value of the constant `RLIM_INFINITY`.

You can verify this in Python.

```
>>> resource.RLIM_INFINITY
-1
```

So, essentially you're trying to set a soft limit of Infinity and a hard limit of less than that. The hard limit *must* be greater than or equal to the soft limit. So instead you can do something like this which should do the trick.

```python
hard_limit = 5 * 1024 * 1024
resource.setrlimit(rsrc, (hard_limit, hard_limit))
```

As for your second question, I'd love to know the answer, which is what brought me to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for part 2**: the `resource` module docs mention this possibility:

> *This module does not attempt to mask platform differences — symbols
>   not defined for a platform will not be available from this module on
>   that platform*.
>
> According to the `bash` `ulimit` source linked to above, it uses
>   `RLIMIT_AS` if `RLIMIT_VMEM` is not defined.

Source: [Limit memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269238/limit-memory-usage-in-python/30269998#30269998)