# How to limit memory usage within a python process

Tags: python, linux, memory, ulimit

I run Python 2.7 on a Linux machine with 16GB Ram and 64 bit OS. A python script I wrote can load too much data into memory, which slows the machine down to the point where I cannot even kill the process any more.

While I can limit memory by calling:

```
ulimit -v 12000000
```

in my shell before running the script, I'd like to include a limiting option in the script itself. Everywhere I looked, the `resource` module is cited as having the same power as `ulimit`. But calling:

```
import resource
_, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_DATA, (12000, hard))
```

at the beginning of my script does absolutely nothing. Even setting the value as low as 12000 never crashed the process. I tried the same with `RLIMIT_STACK`, as well with the same result. Curiously, calling:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('ulimit -v 12000', shell=True)
```

does nothing as well.

What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find any actual usage examples online.

---

edit: For anyone who is curious, using `subprocess.call` doesn't work because it creates a (surprise, surprise!) new process, which is independent of the one the current python program runs in.

Comment: Is there any room to make the program more memory-efficient?

Comment: There is, but that will take a while. At the moment, I need to test it and make sure that it doesn't shut the computer down. And having a fail-safe for the memory will be useful later, too.

Comment: Since it's in Python 2.7, how about switching to Python 3 and using a 2-to-3 converter on your program? Python 3 has several performance improvements over Python 2, some of which are memory-related.

Comment: I will do that -- but at this point, I am just curious if or how limiting memory works in python.

Comment: can't you control what you load into memory? i mean, isn't it YOUR script?

Comment: It's connected to a constant stream (from the Twitter Streaming API), so.. control is not trivial. I will control it at some point, but right now I just want it not to crash.

Comment: This issue comes up in interactive data analysis all the time - you load a large array (say, 8GB) and start your work. Then you inadvertently square the array (a typo in your code, or misunderstanding an API, etc) and now the script requests 64 GB and the system freezes. :P You would much rather have the process killed than restart your computer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`resource.RLIMIT_VMEM`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html?highlight=setrlimit#resource.RLIMIT_VMEM) is the resource [corresponding to `ulimit -v`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def).

`RLIMIT_DATA` [only affects `brk/sbrk` system calls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) while [newer memory managers tend to use `mmap` instead](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/101090-what-differences-between-brk-mmap.html).

The second thing to note is that [`ulimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ulimit)/[`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) only affects the current process and its future children.

Regarding the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLIMIT_VMEM'` message: the [`resource` module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) mention this possibility:

> This module does not attempt to mask platform differences — symbols
>   not defined for a platform will not be available from this module on
>   that platform.

According to the [`bash` `ulimit` source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def) linked to above, it uses `RLIMIT_AS` if `RLIMIT_VMEM` is not defined.

Comment: I don't use multithreading, so I hope that is not the problem. But when I enter `RLIMIT_DATA`, I get the following error message:

    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "my_script.py", line 417, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "my_script.py", line 391, in main
        _, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_VMEM)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RLIMIT_VMEM'`
From the list you referenced, all fields could be found -- except this one. I am trying to run it with Python 3.x right now..