# Running python program under specified amount of memory

Tags: python-3.x

I want to Know how can I make my python program run in such a say that it takes only specified amount of memory **(say x bytes)** to run, and in case of it requires more memory than **x** it should be terminated.

I want something like this:

```
if memory_required > x:
        Terminate program
else:
         Let the program run
```

Comment: I think you'e just maxing out your system. My OS (macOS) reports (and counting)) 60GB of memory usage for Python. This is probably uncompressed and with swap as my system only has 8GB of real memory but I'm not surprised your system slows down. - Update macOS killed the process to protect itself.

Comment: What can I do in case I want to terminate this execution?

Comment: Try Ctrl+D or run 'killall python' in another terminal. Note: the last wil kill every python process running.

Comment: The problem is that nothing works, python become unfunctional

Comment: You just requested at least 16 _million terabytes_ of storage - probably more, depending on how much space `list` instances take and stuff. What did you expect, then? Do you have that much storage on your machine? If it's still unresponsive, you may have to manually unplug it.

Comment: @ForceBru does it mean that a 2d list of size 10^9 can't be declared

Comment: I was Trying this declaration for competitive programming

Comment: @MayankJoshi, as you can see, the language lets you _declare_ lists as huge as you want them to be. However, the actual _computer_ that'll attempt to _execute_ this code may run out of memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269238/limit-memory-usage)