# What do the two numbers returned by Python's resource.RLIMIT_VMEM (or resource.RLIMIT_AS) mean?

Tags: python, memory

Python's [resource](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/resource.html) module allows getting and setting various system resource usage information. In particular, the amount of memory used by a process is available via `resource.RLIMIT_VMEM` (or, on some systems, `resource.RLIMIT_AS` as per [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269998/463213) answer).

When I run the following Python code (using Python 3.7) to print the memory usage, I see a tuple with two values:

```
import resource
print(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS))
```

On Ubuntu 18.04, it prints `(-1, -1)` (which I interpret to mean, both values are infinite).

On Mac OS X 10.4, it prints `(9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807)` (which is approximately an exabyte worth of bytes).

I have two questions about this output:

1. What is the difference between the first number and the second number?
2. How should the reported values like `9223372036854775807` be interpreted - are they numbers of bytes? (Is a very large value just a way of setting a memory limit that is so large it will never be reached?)

Comment: Those are rlimit things, not Python things. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values correspond to `rlim_cur` (the "soft limit") and `rlim_max` (the "hard limit") from the `getrlimit` system call. This is documented in the [library documentation for the resource module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/resource.html).

The value `-1` corresponds to the `resource.RLIM_INFINITY` constant, which means there is no set limit.

The units for `RLIMIT_AS` are defined as bytes, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/resource.html#resource.RLIMIT_AS):

> resource.RLIMIT_AS
>   The maximum area (in bytes) of address space which may be taken by the process.

You can find further Linux-specific information about the meaning of these values on the `getrlimit(2)` man page.